# Python timer similar to javascript timer

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I want to create a dynamic timer on webpage in **python** like this code which is in Javascript:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var seconds = 40;   
var minutes = 01;   
function timer() {seconds--;
  if (seconds == -01) {
   seconds = 59;
   minutes = minutes - 1; }
  else {
   minutes = minutes; }
if (seconds<=9) { seconds = "0" + seconds; }
 time = (minutes<=9 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) +":"+seconds;
if (document.getElementById) { document.getElementById('timertable').innerHTML = time; }
timeout=window.setTimeout("timer();", 1000);
if (minutes == '00' && seconds == '00') { seconds = "00"; window.clearTimeout(timeout); }
}
window.onload = timer;
</script>
```

Some of the conditions the timer must satisfy are:
1>Timer should not re-initialize its value once the other contents of the page reload
2>The duration for which the timer is supposed to run is coming from another HTML page on the basis of choice made by user
Please note that I am using Django on google app engine. Please let me know if I am not clear.Thanks, Sunil

Comment: <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var seconds = 40;   
var minutes = 01;   
function timer() {seconds--;
  if (seconds == -01) {
   seconds = 59;
   minutes = minutes - 1; }
  else {
   minutes = minutes; }
if (seconds<=9) { seconds = "0" + seconds; }
 time = (minutes<=9 ? "0" + minutes : minutes) +":"+seconds;
if (document.getElementById) { document.getElementById('timertable').innerHTML = time; }
timeout=window.setTimeout("timer();", 1000);
if (minutes == '00' && seconds == '00') { seconds = "00"; window.clearTimeout(timeout); }
}
window.onload = timer;
</script>

Comment: To have dynamicity in a webpage you have to use javascript. You can't have a python code embedded. Maximum you can do is use javascript to fetch the timer from a python code, but doesn't looks reasonable in any sense.

Comment: Well thanks Dcrodjer for your reply.I used the above provided javascript And to avoid it re-initialize every time after page reload,I put it in another frame on the same page. But now I stuck on one place.My webpage flow is like this:

Comment: Well thanks Dcrodjer for your reply.I used the above provided javascript And to avoid it re-initialize every time after page reload,I put it in another frame on the same page. But now I stuck on one place.My webpage flow is like this:1>User comes to display.html and select the duration of timer.2>Now display.html calls quiz.html which is divided into two frame.3>First frame source on quiz.html is upper.html and other is lower.html. Now the problem is how I can pass user data from display.html to upper.html which is frame source for quiz page where my timer javascript code is.

Comment: @SRC you may edit and update your question into a nice readable format , instead of posting theses details as comments.

Comment: @SRC: Do not add code in comments.  It's your question.  You can **update** your question to be totally complete and correct.  Please (1) put everything into the question and then (2) drop the comments.

Comment: Due to some technical problem its occurred. Point noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still unsure about what you are trying to achieve.

You may use cookies to store the timer state and initialize the timer following the values present in cookies.
W3School tutorial on cookies: http://www.w3schools.com/JS/js_cookies.asp

If you have a timer which is set up at your server level, you may use an ajax view to fetch the inital time from server and another one to update time as the js timer progresses. You may decrease the requests frequency (maybe 1 per 5 seconds) with the cost of some time loss.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't quite possible in python, as python is server side, and you are displaying user side data. You won't get around javascript in any way, either you will need the timer itself on the js side or you'd need ajax.